# compare 2 array of objects and get the details using Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have 2 array of objects

How can I compare both array of objects and get details of users which is having same id?

```
users:[{
 id:"1",
 displayName: "test"
 email: "abc@gmail.com"
},
{
 id:"2",
 displayName: "test2"
 email: "abc@gmail.com"
}]

listingAgents:[{
 userId:"1",
 listingId:"1354"
]}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?  StackOverflow is based on the idea of helping you with your coding problems, and not on writing your code for you.

Comment: const test = R.find(R.propEq('id',"how can I get listingAgents userID here"))(users) @ScottSauyet

Answer (score 1):

Both arrays have the same objects for the same id ? if yes:

```
users2_id = users2.map(u => u.id)
common_users = users1.filter(u => users2_id.includes(u.id))
```

If not

```
common_users = users1.filter(u => {
    user_2 = users2.find(u_2 => u_2.id === u.id)
    if (!user_2) {
        return false;
    // do your stuff with the two different objects with same id like
    return {...u, ...user_2}
});
```

But be careful with the complexity !

Edit:

Actually for the second part, you could filter one of the array first before playing with it, you 'll remove a lot of objects useless and reduce the number of operations depending of the size of the array !
like:

```
users1_id = users1.map(u => u.id)
users2_filtered = users2.filter(u => users1_id.includes(u.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const users = [{
    id: "1",
    displayName: "test",
    email: "abc@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    displayName: "test2",
    email: "abc@gmail.com"
  }
]

const listingAgents = [{
  userId: "1",
  listingId: "1354"
}]


let results = users.filter((user) => listingAgents.find((x) => x.userId == user.id));
console.log(results)
```

You can filter one of the arrays and then use find to to see if that id exists in other array or not

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output format is not clear.  I'm going to assume that you want to merge the matching users into each listing.  So with input like this:

```js
const users = [
  {id:"1", displayName: "test", email: "abc@gmail.com"},
  {id:"2", displayName: "test2", email: "abc@gmail.com"}
]

const listingAgents = [
  {userId:"1", listingId:"1354"}, 
  {userId:"no match", listingId:"2465"}
]
```

`getListings (users) (listingAgents)` should return this:

```js
[
  {
    "userId": "1",
    "listingId": "1354",
    "id": "1",
    "displayName": "test",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  },
  {
    "userId": "no match",
    "listingId": "2465",
  }
]
```

Since this was tagged with Ramda, note first that we certainly *can* do this with Ramda.   Here's one solution:

```js
const {pipe, indexBy, prop, flip, propOr, o, chain, merge, map} = R

const getListings = pipe (
  indexBy (prop ('id')),
  flip (propOr ({})),
  flip (o) (prop ('userId')),
  chain (merge),
  map
)

const users = [{id:"1", displayName: "test", email: "abc@gmail.com"}, {id:"2", displayName: "test2", email: "abc@gmail.com"}]
const listingAgents = [{userId:"1", listingId:"1354"}, {userId:"no match", listingId:"2465"}]

console .log (getListings (users) (listingAgents))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

It's reasonably concise, but I don't think it's particularly readable.  The [`flip`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/?flip) calls (or equivalently, something using [Ramda's placeholder](https://ramdajs.com/docs/?__) make code seem much less clear to me.  Instead, we might go for vanilla JS, with something like this:

```js
const getListings = (users) => (agents) =>  
  agents .map ((agent) => ({
    ... agent,
    ... (users .find (({id}) => id == agent.userId) ?? {})
  }))

const users = [{id:"1", displayName: "test", email: "abc@gmail.com"}, {id:"2", displayName: "test2", email: "abc@gmail.com"}]
const listingAgents = [{userId:"1", listingId:"1354"}, {userId:"no match", listingId:"2465"}]

console .log (getListings (users) (listingAgents))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

There is one real advantage, though, to that Ramda version.  It indexes the users only once and does not search through them on every call.  (That is what `indexBy` does here.)

If we wanted to do that in our vanilla code, we might end up with something like this:

```js
const getListings3 = (
  users, 
  index = Object .fromEntries (users .map (u => [u.id, u]))
) => (agents) => 
  agents .map ((agent) => ({
    ... agent,
    ... (index [agent.userId] ?? {})
  }))
```

or equivalently, this:

```js
const getListings3 = (users) => {
  const index = Object .fromEntries (users .map (u => [u.id, u]))
  return (agents) => 
    agents .map ((agent) => ({
      ... agent,
      ... (index [agent.userId] ?? {})
    }))
}
```

In either case, now I'm on the fence between whether the Ramda version or the vanilla one is more readable.